# Equivalent of `package.json' and `package-lock.json` for `pip`

Tags: python, pip, dependencies, conda, requirements.txt

Package managers for `JavaScript` like `npm` and `yarn` use a `package.json` to specify 'top-level' dependencies, and create a [lock-file](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-locks) to keep track of the specific versions of *all* packages (i.e. top-level *and* sub-level dependencies) that are installed as a result.

In addition, the `package.json` allows us to make a distinction between types of top-level dependencies, such as *production* and *development*.

For `Python`, on the other hand, we have `pip`. I suppose the `pip` equivalent of a `lock`-file would be the result of `pip freeze > requirements.txt`.

However, if you maintain only this single `requirements.txt` file, it is difficult to distinguish between top-level and sub-level dependencies (you would need for e.g. `pipdeptree -r` to figure those out). This can be a real pain if you want to remove or change top-level dependencies, as it is easy to be left with orphaned packages (as far as I know, `pip` [does not remove sub-dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10284948) when you `pip uninstall` a package).

**Now, I wonder**: Is there some convention for dealing with different types of these `requirements` files and distinguishing between top-level and sub-level dependencies with `pip`?

For example, I can imagine having a `requirements-prod.txt` which contains only the top-level requirements for the production environment, as the (simplified) equivalent of `package.json`, and a `requirements-prod.lock`, which contains the output of `pip freeze`, and acts as my `lock`-file. In addition I could have a `requirements-dev.txt` for development dependencies, and so on and so forth.

I would like to know if this is the way to go, or if there is a better approach.

p.s. The same question could be asked for `conda`'s `environment.yml`.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/58218592

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There are at least three good options available today:

1. [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) uses [`pyproject.toml` and `poetry.lock` files](https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/#installing-with-poetrylock), much in the same way that `package.json` and lock files work in the JavaScript world.

   This is now my preferred solution.
2. [Pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv) uses [`Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`](https://github.com/pypa/pipfile), also much like you describe the JavaScript files.

Both Poetry and Pipenv do more than just dependency management. Out of the box, they also create and maintain virtual environments for your projects.

3. [`pip-tools`](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools) provides `pip-compile` and `pip-sync` commands. Here, `requirements.in` lists your direct dependencies, often with loose version constraints and `pip-compile` generates locked down `requirements.txt` files from your `.in` files.

   This used to be my preferred solution. It's backwards-compatible (the generated `requirements.txt` can be processed by `pip`) and the `pip-sync` tool ensures that the virtualenv exactly matches the locked versions, removing things that aren't in your "lock" file.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, which pointed me to [this interesting post](https://nvie.com/posts/better-package-management/). However, I am hesitant in adopting `pipenv`, with its use of `virtualenv` instead of `conda`, because I really like (and rely on) `conda`'s ability to manage `Python` versions.

Comment: That's another point in favour of `pip-tools`, IMO. It doesn't try to do too much for you.

Comment: And `pip-tools` also takes care of "it is easy to be left with orphaned packages" since it removes anything that's not in the requirements file.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll have a look at it. Does introduce another dependency though. ;-)

Comment: Yes, to work around limitations of `pip` itself. There are manual workarounds using just `pip` but then you're a lot more likely to make a mistake. The fact that `pip-compile` outputs a `pip`-compatible `requirements.txt` file means you can just `pip install -r requirements.txt` on new machines and then work with `pip-tools` moving forward. I usually install `pip-tools` into new environments on creation.

Comment: What I need is, I'd like to run `pip install` and generate the lock file automatically and commit the lockfile in source code as well. So next time, in a new system, I can install the exact same package versions by reference lockfile more than to install some newer version on-fly.

Comment: @BMW, are you asking for clarification about something? Both options listed here do what you want, just with slightly different syntax.

Comment: Jumping in here to add a +1 to `pip-tools`, I like how lightweight it is and how compatible it is with any other tool out there, since it's output is just a plain old requirements.txt.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and I came up with a more generic and simple solution. I am using the well-known `requirements.txt` for all explicit dependencies and `requirements.lock` as a list of all packages including sub dependencies.

I personally like to manage `python`, `pip` and `setuptools` via the distributions builtin package manager and install pip dependencies inside a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html).

Usually you would start installing all directly required dependencies. This will pull in all sub dependencies as well. If you are not using a virtual environment make sure to add the `--user` flag.

```bash
# If you already have a requirements file
pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# If you start from scratch
pip3 install <package>
```

If you want to upgrade your packages, you [have multiple options here as well](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2720014/14348748). Since I am using a virtual environment I will always update all packages. However you are free to only update your direct requirements. If they need an update of their dependencies, those will be pulled in as well, everything else will be left untouched.

```bash
# Update all outdated packages (excluding pip and setuptools itself)
pip3 install -r <(pip3 list --outdated --format freeze --exclude pip setuptools | cut -d '=' -f1) --upgrade

# Update explicitly installed packages, update sub dependencies only if required.
pip3 install -r <(cut -d '=' -f1 requirements.txt) --upgrade
```

Now we come to the tricky part: Saving back our requirements file. Make sure that the previous requirements file is checked into git, so if anything goes wrong you have a backup.

Remember that we want to differentiate between packages explicitly installed (`requirements.txt`) and packages including their dependencies (`requirements.lock`).

If you have not yet setup a requirements.txt I suggest running the following command. Note that [it will not include sub dependencies if they are already satisfied by another package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73669713/14348748). This means `requests` will not be included in the list, if it was already satisfied by another package. You might still want to add that manually, if your script explicitly relies on such a package.

```
pip3 list --not-required --format freeze --exclude pip --exclude setuptools > requirements.txt
```

If you already have a `requirements.txt` you can update it by using [this sed trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73669746/14348748). This will leave all sub-dependencies outside, which we will only include in the `requirements.lock` in the next step.

```bash
pip3 freeze -r requirements.txt | sed -n '/## The following requirements were added by pip freeze:/q;p' | sponge requirements.txt
```

Finally we can output **all dependencies** to a `requirements.lock` file which will be our complete list of all packages and versions. If we have issues to reproduce an issue, we can always come back to this lock file and run our code with the previously working dependencies.

```bash
# It is important to use the -r option here, so pip will differenciate between directly required packages and dependencies.
pip3 freeze -r requirements.txt > requirements.lock
```