# Mark a pip dependency as explicit installed

Tags: pip, python-packaging, requirements.txt

I want to differentiate between packages that I have explicitly installed, and packages pulled in as dependency. You can do that by using the `--not-required` option:

```bash
pip3 list --not-required --format freeze
```

However if I have a package that requires for example the `requests` package, then it will be automatically pulled in, if installed via `requirements.txt`. Installing requests via `pip install requests` will not put it in the list of `--not-required` packages. Not even adding it to the `requirements.txt` file would help setting this packages as required.

It seems that pip will always exclude those sub dependencies and only print those packages that are not dependent by another package. Is that true? How could I work around that without adding additional dependencies for package management. It seems that there is no such clever builtin option, right?